# How to change lock screen clock display on Samsung Galaxy A3?

Tags: app-widgets, clock, lock-screen-widgets

On the lock screen of a Samsung Galaxy A3, the clock is displayed in two rows:

```
14
18
```

I'd like it to be displayed as God intended:

```
14:18
```

And I've spent an hour trying to get it this way, and nothing helps.

There's nothing in the Settings to customize the display of the clock.  There are apps that are clock widgets, but they can be enabled only for the "home" screen, once the device is unlocked, not for the Lock screen.

How can I change the display of the lock screen clock?

Android version 7.0, Samsung Experience version 8.1.

Comment: Use some other *lock screen* app from the Play Store.. You cannot customize the stock one.

Comment: Any particular recommendations?  I tried Next from Microsoft, and it worked more or less ok, but one day the lock screen began to behave like this: it shows the built-in lock screen with the two-row clock, then when I unlock, it shows the Next's lock screen which I have to unlock as well, and this is one unlock too many for my taste.

Comment: I've spent several hours but still no soloution. However, here's a link to a workaround provided you don't mind a notification on your lock screen:
https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/Horizontal-Lock-Screen-Clock-Bluetooth-Volume-Work-Around/td-p/146676

Answer (score 1):

To change the clock style on the A3:

go to Apps>Settings>Lock screen & security>Always on display. Select the digital clock then click on clock style (bottom left)>select the face of your choice. Click on Apply at he top right.

Enjoy.

Comment: No.  The question asks about the lock screen, not the always-on screen.  The solution, while helpful for the always-on screen, does nothing for the lock screen.